# Ag Grid header checkbox selection - check/uncheck for all checkboxes does`t work

Tags: javascript, checkbox, ag-grid, selection, virtualization

I'm stuck with one problem and I need your help!

So,
We have **Ag Grid** table with 1000 and more rows.
In every row, in one column we are able to add a checkbox that contains some needed data to make some operation, e.g. using "id" or"value"(always different). If I click on the checkbox and after clicking on the button - the page navigates me to another page.
We are also able to check all checkboxes - 1000, 2000, and so on.

The problem when using **Ag Grid** - **Row virtualisation** - Only renders a certain number of rows, say 60. The rest - when scrolling.
We use lots of cellRenderers and it's not possible to add `suppressRowVitrualisation: true`.
The same is with the `rowBuffer` - it's not possible to increase it to 1000.
When adding these settings, the page freezes.

Is it possible to use `checkboxselection: true, headercheckboxselection: true` to override it by adding some data inside every checkbox("id" and "value" - always different) and at the same time, the selection of all rows and all checkboxes in the table works, whether the table has 10 or 2000 rows?